# which laws in India deal with property claim by the heir of a living parent if any?

Tags: india

are there any laws in India that deal with this concept ? or is it a general rule that children do not have a claim to their living parents property. for example the Hindu inheritence law states that the son of a living mother has no right to her property

Comment: Surely the (presumably) default case of "you don't have the right to another person's property" would apply unless there's some law to the contrary? If mom has inherited from her deceased husband, then it's her property now. It seems like maybe you're looking for something which clarifies whether a widow automatically inherits everything from her deceased husband or whether their children (or possibly specifically sons) inherit directly from their deceased father irrespective of whether or not their mother still lives.

Comment: @brhans Living spouses have claims to each other's property in community property jurisdictions, but there is no comparable parent-child right while a parent is living in most cases. Historically dower rights also limited alienability during life between spouses.

Comment: @ohwilleke what about maintainence (aka basic neccesities) is that a right adult children can claim from their parents ?

Comment: Adult sons and married adult daughters have no right to maintenance from their parents in India. Minor children and unmarried adult daughters do have such a right., at least while their parents are living. https://www.deccanchronicle.com/lifestyle/viral-and-trending/111121/adult-children-no-right-to-maintenance.html I don't know how that issue is handled in the probate context in India. A right to maintenance is not necessarily a right to property , however, and would frequently be provided "in kind."